# Determining last index reference in a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Is there a way of finding out the last index that was referenced in a dictionary? For instance,

```
Dictionary<string,string> exampleDic;

...

exampleDic["Temp"] = "ASDF"

...
```

Is there a way to somehow retrieve "Temp" without storing it as a variable?

Comment: Dictionary class doesn't have such a capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own dictionary

```
public class MyDic : Dictionary<String, String>
{
    public string LastKey { get; set; }

    public String this[String key]
    {
        get
        {
            LastKey = key;
            return this.First(x => x.Key == key).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            LastKey = key;
            base[key] = value; // if you use this[key] = value; it will enter an infinite loop and cause stackoverflow
        }
    }
```

Then in your code

```
    MyDic dic = new MyDic();
    dic.Add("1", "one");
    dic.Add("2", "two");
    dic.Add("3", "three");

    dic["1"] = "1one";

    dic["2"] = dic.LastKey; // LastKey : "1"

    dic["3"] = dic.LastKey; // LastKey : "2";
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There's nothing that stores this (it's a pretty unusual requirement) so you'd have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for Generic Dictionary:

```
public class GenericDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }

    public V this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            Key = key;
            return this.First(x => x.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Key = key;
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> exampleDic;
...
exampleDic["Temp"] = "ASDF"
var key = exampleDic.Key;
```